# Set return type based on last element in array passed as an argument

Tags: typescript, types, orm

I have 2 types Icon and Subcategory, which are related to each other.

```
interface Subcategory {
  id: number
  iconId: number
  name: string
}

interface Icon {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

Example objects:

```
subcategory = {
  id: 1,
  iconId: 1,
  name: "Restaurant"
}
```

```
icon = {
  id: 1,
  name: "payments"
}
```

I wanted to create a function which allows to get name for Icon for specified Subcategory. It could be something like this `subcategories[0].icon.name`.

I created function which takes:

1. object (f.e. `subcategories[0]`)
2. location to icon name as array (f.e. `["iconId", "name"]`)
3. array of related records (f.e. `[icons]` which is array of all icons)

If `location` length is equal to `records` then I expect to return object of the same type as elements in last object in `records` array. For `get(subcategories[0], ["iconId"], [icons]` I expect to get `Icon`.

If `location` length has one more element than `records` then I expect to return object which has the same type as this property in object. For `get(subcategories[0], ["iconId", "name"], [icons]` I expect to get `string`.

I tried to set types for arguments, but I cannot get correct return type. **Which types I should use for function arguments to get correct type for returned value?**

```
export const get = (
  sourceEntity,
  location,
  records
) => {
  let currentEntity = sourceEntity;
  let id;
  for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    id = currentEntity[location[i]];
    currentEntity = records[i].find((r) => r.id === id);
  }
  if (location.length === records.length) {
    return currentEntity;
  } else if (location.length === records.length + 1) {
    return currentEntity[location[location.length - 1]];
  } else {
    throw new Error("Incorrect location.length or records.length");
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey @pmasior, first question: shouldn't `icons` be an array, like `let icons: Icon[] = [{id: 1, name: 'payments']` oder better be renamed to `icon`? Second question: What do you think about using an `interface SubcategoryWithIcon extends Subcategory { icon: Icon}` 
and a `function joinSubcategoriesWithIcons(subcategories: Subcategory[], icons: Icon[]): SubcategoryWithIcon[]` so can navigate through the objects directly? Would also be possible to just use  something like `const sub: SubCategoryWithIcon = {...subcategories[0], icon: icons.find(i=> i.id === subcategories[0].iconId)}`

Comment: Hi @Jupiter. Thanks for your reply. Yes, `icons` should be an array. I edited post. In application I have more types and I want use generic types to avoid write functions for all relations, so I have to think about your solutions.

Comment: Of course you can also just use `const ref = icons.find(i => i.id === subcategories[0].iconId)`. So you don't need a separate interface. Just use Array.find for all of your relations